# Code in IntelliJ IDEA marked with compiler error where it works fine in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, servlets, intellij-idea

I'm trying to setup my IntelliJ workspace to do development on an eclipse project. One of the things I've run into is rather confusing:

```
Error:(24, 8) java: SomeClass.java:24: getHeader(java.lang.String) in org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse cannot implement getHeader(java.lang.String) in javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; attempting to use incompatible return type
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.lang.String
```

The problem is the following class definition:

```
public class SomeClass extends MockHttpServletResponse {
```

The problem seems to be because MockHttpServletResponse implements `Collection<String> getHeaders(String)` as `public List getHeaders(String name)`. Here, I can see that the implementing method uses a raw `List` where the parent asks for a generic `Collection` typed with `String`. Aside from being potentially not type-safe, why would IntelliJ mark this as a complier error instead of a warning?

I have no option of changing any of these libraries. I'm simply trying to make work in IntellJ 14 what already works without complaints in Eclipse 4.3+.

### EDIT:

I have since updated to IntelliJ 15.0, and the project is using Java 1.7 now instead of 1.6. I am still running into this issue with IntelliJ, but the issue is not presenting itself at all in Eclipse. I can compile the project using existing Ant scripts via IntelliJ, but I cannot debug through the IDE.

Here is my class definition

```
public class ExecutableServletResponse extends MockHttpServletResponse {
  ...
```

Here is the error showing in my 'Messages' pane:

```
Error:(24, 8) java: getHeader(java.lang.String) in org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse cannot implement getHeader(java.lang.String) in javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
                return type java.lang.Object is not compatible with java.lang.String
```

The project SDK is using version 1.7 (1.7.0_79 to be exact). Language level is 7. Module SDK and Language Levels match the project.

I've tried using the eclipse compiler, but the app still doesn't fully compile, and will fail to run presumably because it fails to compile this class, and a whole part of the webapp doesn't compile as a result.

Here's a screenshot of my error, FWIW:

[image]

Comment: Are you using the same JDK in both cases?

Comment: And the same compliance level?

Comment: According to my project settings (using ctrl+alt+shift+s) shows that I'm using 1.6 as the project SDK and 1.6 as the language level (for project and all modules). This appears to be the same as I have in Eclipse (using jdk1.6.0_45 and 1.6 JDK complience)

Comment: Hmm...Spring Javadoc says that [getHeaders](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletResponse.html#getHeaders-java.lang.String-) correctly returns List<String>. Also, it's complaining about there being a method `Object getHeader(String)` rather than `String getHeader(String)`, not about getHeaders. Did you override getHeader in your subclass?

Comment: Are you using Maven? In IntelliJ, when you select File -> Project Settings and then Project, what does it say is the SDK? (1.7.0_79, I presume). If you open a terminal (Alt-F12) and type java -version, how does it respond?

Comment: @rajah9 Not using Maven. This is an ANT build. `java -version` is telling me it's using 1.8.0_45, which is where my `JAVA_HOME` points to... but all the settings in IDEA are told to use 1.7.

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock We're not using the latest version of Spring... Not sure exactly which one, but it's one where the method signature is `public List getHeaders(String)`, but the overridden signature is `Collection<String> getHeaders(String)`. Not overriding it in subclass.. only overriding `getInputStream`

Comment: What version of org.springframework:spring-mock are you using? I just compiled it in IntelliJ with no problems with v 2.0.8.

Comment: @rajah9 According to MANIFEST.MF in `spring-mock.jar`, version 2.0.6

Comment: Is it possible that your IntelliJ set-up is somehow using different servlet dependency? I just tried it and Spring 2.5.6 + servlet 3 produces this error, while Spring 2.5.6 with servlet 2.5 does not. There is an [issue in Spring JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8529) about incompatibility with Servlet 3, which was fixed with Spring 3.1.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt All I know is that when I ctrl-click into the classes, the jar files that are being used are the same in both IDEs. I imported the eclipse .project file into IDEA, so all of the dependencies are there. I don't know which version of the servlet API is used, but it's one that is included in gwt-user.jar from a derivatave of GWT 2.6.1 (likely modified slightly to work with this project).

Comment: @agent154 Have you tried switching the compiler to ECJ, in case that might make a difference?

Comment: There is an issue in Spring Jira, as Bohuslav pointed out, which seems to be fixed in 3.1, I've just tested it and it works well for me. If you said that you're not using that function, as a workaround you could copy the necessary code of MockHttpServletResponse and implement the original interface with your class instead of extending the spring class. Then you can modify the method to return a Collection and avoid compiling MockHttpServletResponse. Unless you can upgrade your spring libraries to a newer version where this issue is fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are seeing the error in your class, but the real issue is that the Spring mock library is not compatible with the Servlet Specification you are using. This may happen if you upgraded to the Servlet 3.0 Spec (or added a dependency that pulled it in transitively). Check your dependencies and ensure that either:

- Only Servlet 2.5 is provided, or
- You are using a version of Spring that is compatible with Servlet 3.0. Also ensure that all of your Spring dependencies are using the same version.

This combination should work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

as should this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But this will fail:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The fact that it works in Eclipse but not in IntelliJ suggests that you have multiple dependencies that provide the same classes. There is no guarantee as to which jar the system will use to load the class. This may either be because you have both `servlet-api` and `javaee-web-api` on your classpath or because you have both `spring-mock` and `spring-test` on your classpath. After version 2.0.8, the classes in `spring-mock` were moved to `spring-test` and only version 3.1.0.RELEASE and higher of `spring-test` are compatible with Servlet 3.0.

Comment: It would appear that this is it. I removed `spring-mock.jar` from the IntelliJ classpath, and the error went away. It turns out that `spring-test` was also available, so that problem was resolved.